# Borrar fila de una tabla con php

Tags: php, sql-server, sql

Hola buenas tardes nuevo en el foro y tengo la siguiente duda.

tengo este código que me carga en una tabla todo lo que hay dentro de la base de datos, el problema esta al momento de borrar por ID...

Gracias de antemano.

```
<form name="frmInsertarFecha" action="" method="POST">
        <table style="width:100%" class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Fecha Inicio</th>
                <th>Fecha Termino</th>
                <th>Estado</th> 
                <th>Accion</th>
                <th>Accion</th>
            </tr>
            <?php

            $consulta = "SELECT * FROM R_FECHA";
            $ejecutar = sqlsrv_query($con, $consulta);

            $i = 0;

            while ($fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array($ejecutar)) {
                $id = $fila['R_FECHA_ID'];
                $fechaIni = $fila['R_FECHA_INICIO'];
                $fechaTer = $fila['R_FECHA_TERMINO'];
                $estado = $fila['R_FECHA_ACTIVO'];
                $i++;
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fechaIni; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $fechaTer; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $estado; ?></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="btnEstado" name="btnEstado" value="Modificar Estado"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="btnBorrar" name="btnBorrar" value="Borrar"></td>
        <!--                    <td><input type="date" name="fInicio" id="fInicio"></td>
                    <td><input type="date" name="fTermino" id="fTermino"></td> 
        </td>-->                <?php
                    if (isset($_GET['btnBorrar'])) {
                        $borrar_id = $_GET['btnBorrar'];
                        $borrar = "DELETE FROM R_FECHA WHERE R_FECHA_ID = '$borrar_id'";

                        $ejecutar = sqlsrv_query($con, $borrar);
                        if ($ejecutar) {
                            echo "<script>alert('Ha sido Borrado')</script>";
                        }
                    }
                    ?>


                </tr>
```

Comment: Que es lo que te marca actualmente de error, o qué hace? y qué es lo que intentas hacer?

Comment: Estoy haciendo un CRUD hasta el momento puedo ingresar campos a sqlserver y mostrarlos en una tabla html. Lo que no puedo hacer es borrar la fila de la tabla de base de datos mediante el ID

Comment: Cual es el error que te muestra al borrar o que es lo que hace o no hace tu codigo?.

Comment: El botón btnBorrar lo cambie a submit y hace la acción como de f5 pero no hace nada mas y no me muestra error.

Comment: Dale un echo al $_GET['btnBorrar'] para ver que trae, alomejor viene vacio y por eso no hace nada

Answer (score 0):

Mira tienes algunos errores, primero que nada tu formulario esta enviando los datos por el método `POST` y estas intentando capturar el id a borrar a traves del arreglo `$_GET` que es para cuando los datos del formulario lo mandas por ese método, es decir cuando en tu formulario el atributo `method` es igual a `"get"` o no esta establecido y se asume por defecto. El otro error es que estas intentando obtener el id de tu `botón de eliminar` el cual en su valor no tiene el id del registro que vas a eliminar. La solución seria si estas pasando los datos del formulario por `POST`, capturar los datos a travez del arreglo `$_POST` y lo segundo es cambiar tus `inputs` de tipo `botón` por un elemento `button` con el cual podras cambiarle el valor al atributo value y saber que id quieres eliminar. Te quedaria asi la ultima parte de tu codigo:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fechaIni; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fechaTer; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $estado; ?></td>
    <td><button type="submit" id="btnEstado" name="btnEstado" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">Modificar Estado</button></td>
    <td><button type="submit" id="btnBorrar" name="btnBorrar" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">Borrar</button></td>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['btnBorrar'])) {
            $borrar_id = $_POST['btnBorrar'];
            $borrar = "DELETE FROM R_FECHA WHERE R_FECHA_ID = '$borrar_id'";

            $ejecutar = sqlsrv_query($con, $borrar);
            if ($ejecutar) {
                echo "<script>alert('Ha sido Borrado')</script>";
            }
        }
    ?>
</tr>
```